# How to compare city obtained from geolocation with stored cities in my database and if city exists pass the id through ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, vue.js

My script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   search = new Vue({
     el: '#offers',
     data: {
        data: [],
        authType: '{{uid}}',
        key : '1',
        with_ : 'district',
    },

mounted() { 
 var self = this; 
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( success, error );
    data = {};
    data['auth-token'] = this.authType;
    data['key'] = this.key;
    data['with_'] = this.with_;

            function success( position ) {/* geolocation success callback */
                var GEOCODING = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + position.coords.latitude + '%2C' + position.coords.longitude + '&language=en';
                $.getJSON( GEOCODING ).done( function( location ) {

                    $('#country').html(location.results[0].address_components[5].long_name);
                    $('#state').html(location.results[0].address_components[4].long_name);
                    $('#city').html(location.results[0].address_components[2].long_name);
                    $('#address').html(location.results[0].formatted_address);
                    $('#latitude').html(position.coords.latitude);
                    $('#longitude').html(position.coords.longitude);


    data['city'] = location.results[0].address_components[2].long_name;

 $.ajax({ 
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/alpha/get/", 
    data: data,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function (e) { 
      if (e.status == 1) { 

      }
    },
  });
  $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/city/",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(e) {
            if (e.status == 1) { 
              self.cities = e.data;
            }
          },
     });
   });
   }   
  },
});
</script>
```

Now with `data['city']`, I am passing the obtained city from geolocation. But I need to compare with the list of cities obtained through the ajax request `http://127.0.0.1:8000/city/` and send the corresponding id as `data['city']` instead of name.
I get json response of getting list of city as

```
 {"status": true, "data": [{"id": 1, "name": "Palakkad"}, {"id": 2, "name": "kochi"}]}`
```

I need to compare the obtained city from geolocation with the above list and if city exists, I need to pass the corresponding ID as `data['city']`.

Please help me to have a solution for the same. I am very weak in js and this is my first project. I am a beginner. Please help me to provide a solution?

Comment: Most of your uses of `data` should be `this.data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, given an object with city data and a city name, you want to get the matching city's id from the city data (if there is a match). The function below should work for you.

It looks through `cities.data` to find an entry where the name matches. If one is found, the `id` is returned, otherwise, `null` is returned.

```js
const cities = {"status": true, "data": [{"id": 1, "name": "Palakkad"}, {"id": 2, "name": "kochi"}]};
const cityName = 'Palakkad';

function findCity(name) {
  const foundCity = cities.data.find(entry => entry.name === name);
  
  return foundCity ? foundCity.id : null;
}

console.log(findCity(cityName));
console.log(findCity('Houston'));
```